# App that will communicate with server - Cordova?

Tags: cordova, mobile

I'm a student of software engineering looking into learning some extra mobile development who's been doing a lot of c and c++.

I want to create an app that has two interfaces. One has a button that when pressed will sent a count to a server, and another interface (a different user) that can see the count total in real time of that button.

I find myself fairly good at learning new languages, can someone point me in which direction to go to learn how to create such a simple feature in a app? Will I need to learn php or some sort of dotnet?

I was told Cordova would do well for this.

Comment: If you are trying to learn mobile development best way is start with a specific platform sdk like android or ios. Purpose of using cordova is to build application for several mobile platforms at once. And the things you would learn and encounter while developing with native sdks are significantly difference when you do it in cordova.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to learn mobile development best way is start with a specific platform sdk like android or ios. Purpose of using cordova is to build application for several mobile platforms at once. And the things you would learn and encounter while developing with native sdks are significantly different from when you do it in cordova.

To create real time two way communication you could use any of the follwings.

1. https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ (ios/android)
2. http://jwebsocket.org/ (android)
3. http://parse.com/ (ios/android)
4. http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/

OR Use sockets with you own php/.Net server

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2014/02/android-sercerclient-example-client.html